In Django, how to upload an epub and display the epub's xhtml contents as a (checkbox) list for further processing of xhtml file content?
High-level overview: I have a Django project, and I'm trying to create an interface to allow users to upload an epub. On form submission, the epub would be processed (unzipped), and its xhtml contents would be display as a list of s on the new page. This new page would also be a form/view. The user could then select the xhtml files they want and submit that form. The selected xhtml files would then have their text extracted and display on the third and final view.
View 1: Form to allow users to choose an epub from their computer.
View 2: Form that displays XHTML files extracted from the uploaded epub.
View 3: Displays text extracted from the selected XHTML files.
I have the view to upload the epub, but this is where I get lost. How can I process the epub and pass the files to use in the new view?
If there's a different way to process the epubs contents rather than unzipping the file, that would work, too!
